# Is it correct to say Newtonian mechanics is a subset of Quantum mechanics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics

I grew up in a three dimensional (3D) reality described quite well by Newtonian mechanics as opposed to the reality described by Quantum mechanics. That is I could go to bed at night without worrying about the bed disappearing during the night plus I could watch the full moon rise in the east before retiring and not have to worry about it disappearing during the night. I was quite confident that it would appear in the west when I arose from my nights rest. Is it correct to say that Newtonian mechanics is a subset of Quantum mechanics?

Comment: 'Subset' is probably the wrong word, but yes, QM reduces to the familiar classical mechanics in the so-called classical limit. See the [correspondence principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correspondence_principle).

Comment: Everything you say until that last question is irrelevant to the post (or is it?)

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform +1 for "or is it"

Comment: I suggest you read this [excellent article by Ed Taylor.](http://www.eftaylor.com/pub/QMtoNewtonsLaws.pdf) The comments below by [CuriousOne](http://physics.stackexchange.com/users/56997/curiousone) have me thinking more deeply about the issue, but what is in that article is standard fare and answers your question at a very deep level.

Answer (score 4):

You are falling into the trap of confusing theories with reality. Theories do not form reality. Reality forms theories. Theories can *explain* reality, at least partly. It is also quite normal to have different theories co-existing, which explain different parts of reality at the same time.

The interesting part is usually the borders between them, where unexpected things may happen. But this is simply an expression of the maths breaking down (or being too simple to be applied to more complex cases), it is nothing to worry about, and the fact that different theories describe different parts of nature does not in itself imply that there is a "problem" somewhere.

> I grew up in a three dimensional (3D) reality described quite well by Newtonian mechanics

You certainly did not grow up in the part of reality that is described by Newtonian mechanics, unless you happen to be a celestial body flying through deep space. Newtonian mechanics breaks down at our everyday level the moment you get up from bed. They do not account for 99.999% of the "features" of reality you see around you any second of your live. The parts of reality explained by quantum theories are vastly larger and closer to our everyday lives.

*And* there are plenty of other classical theories (electromagnetism, chemistry etc.) which, while not being "complete" to cover the whole Mess[tm] either, are hugely more relevant to us than Newtonian mechanics.

Of course, Newton has the advantage that people can easily understand his rules, and they serve as a great introduction to how to think about problems in a scientific way, while I would doubt the sanity of everyone who claims to fully understand QM...

Answer (score 2):

Newtonian physics is described perfectly by classical mechanics equations.

For dimensions where the [Heisenberg uncertainty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncertainty_principle) has a definitive value quantum mechanical formulations have to be used. Macroscopic matter, a ball for example,  is composed by ~10^23 atoms or molecules . Atoms and molecules are in the quantum mechanical regime and bulk matter rests on this underlying framework.

> Is it correct to say that Newtonian mechanics is a subset of Quantum mechanics?

The correct  expression is that the classical regime *emerges* from the quantum mechanical regime . *Emerges* covers the complicated mathematical processes that are involved in going to the limit of large dimensions and integrating over the many variables which are involved in describing macroscopic matter by its elementary constituents, so as to get the classical mechanics equations.

Answer (score 0):

For *large-scale* physics, Einstein's *General Relativity* reduces to *Newtonian theory of gravitation*. Yet for *small-scale* physics, *Quantum Mechanics* would lose its *indeterministic* Nature (the so-called *Classical Limit* for vanishingly small hbar).

What could complicate the situation is *relativistic velocities* which could happen in both regimes. When applied to *small scale* physics, then *Relativistic Quantum Mechanics* will be born (which is also called *Quantum Field Theory*) and it is the most fundamental way to study *small-scale* Universe.

Three fundamental forces of Nature, *Electromagnetic*, *Weak* and *Strong* interactions are about to be unified in the context of quantum field theory. But so far, the unification fails to include Gravity. That's why we have *two physics;* one for small-scale and one for large-scale.

And the reason we are not worrying of things you mentioned in your post, *IS NOT* that they are not going to happen. It is because that the probability of seeing those weird things in the the course of our lives (which is billions of times smaller than the age of Universe) is vanishingly small. A good measure for those weird things to happen would be the lifetime of proton which *IS NOT* infinitely long but long enough that we *almost* will never see it.(The reason proton is thought to be *stable* is that it has a life time that is at least 100000000000000000000000 times the age of Universe in an underlying *supersymmetry* model of particle physics.) This is why we think we are safe :) (unless interfered with a *Local* supernova or gamma-ray burst or even Star Wars!)

Short Answer: It is not correct to say, "Newtonian mechanics is a subset of Quantum mechanics." (Please follow below discussions for details of this conclusion.)

Comment: Quantum mechanics is not a simple deformation of Newtonian mechanics. If you could vary $\hbar$, the major quantum phenomena (like atoms etc.) would change scale (quadratically in $\hbar$), but they wouldn't disappear. The limit $\hbar \to 0$ is therefor not well defined. The classical limit can be reconstructed from the quantum world trough decoherence, but we are still teaching this 100% wrong in most undergrad classes on QM, it seems.

Comment: Hi dear CuriousOne. Would you please elaborate more on the arguments you made. It is greatly appreciated. Not that I don't want to do research on your statements but I see nice logics "in-between" lines. Thanks,

Comment: There isn't much to elaborate. If you change $\hbar$, atoms will change their size, but they will stay atoms. If you set $\hbar=0$ , then the Schroedinger equation becomes $V\psi=0$, which is completely useless. The handwaving explanations that you have heard in school are completely nonsensical. Newtonian mechanics doesn't contain matter and quantum mechanics never contains Newtonian paths without decoherence. The correct explanation for that was given by Mott in 1929 for the case of alpha particle tracks and it's basically a precursor to modern weak measurement and decoherence.

Comment: Thanks CuriousOne. I am satisfied now and will edit my response accordingly. Yes, it is correct that we have learned some things handwavingly which must be revisited in more depth including the reduction of quantum mechanics into classical mechanics. However, let's not forget that having hbar being exactly equal to zero would make Heisenberg Uncertainty Principle into a certainty according to which the path an object takes for travel between two points would be 100% deterministic. The reason they called it "classical limit," I believe, is the path integral spectra collapsing into one path.

Comment: Take a good look at the path integral, again... can you see the convergence problem?

Comment: Which one do you believe more in? Path integral formalism of Quantum Mechanics or the Uncertainty embedded in Nature?

Comment: I don't believe in anything, especially not trivializing mathematical hand waves. There are somewhat trivial one-parameter limits in physics, like the transition from special relativity to classical mechanics, but they are few an far inbetween. The transition from quantum mechanics to the classical regime is not one of them and there is no rational reason to pretend that it can be trivialized.

Comment: I can see what you mean and I truly respect that. The convergence is guaranteed only under a very specific condition in the path integral yet we are not making any such assumption in the uncertainty of a measurement. There are few assumptions in QFT that are yet to be justified but taken as axioms and used extensively. So, I really don't see the conflict in here. Just different interpretation of Nature. However, I do admit that "Classical Limit" has been handwaving. Thanks for being kind and patient. It was informative.